# How to check which command arrives at SQL server when send using ADO? Is there a logfile?

Tags: sql-server, ado

I have a general question about using ADO together with SQL-server 2008express (Microsoft).

When sending a SQL command to the server from let's say an EXCEL application, is there away (eg using the management studio) to see EXACTLY what the command the server received looked like? I know how it looked like in the VBA debugger, but sometimes strange things like commas turning into dots happen. It wold be much easier to track such bugs down this way.... Can i create some kind of log file on the server where I see everything that was tried ?

Regards Lumpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a full edition of SQL Server (even Developer edition will do), use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to capture the queries. If you don't have access to the Microsoft tool there is an [open source profiler](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) available for express.